# Table cell border

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf, ruby-on-rails-plugins, prawn, prawnto

This is the 2x2 table I need to generate:

```
r1c1  r1c2
r2c1  r2c1
      ----
```

In other words I should print the bottom border of the bottom right cell. This is my code:

show.pdf.prawn

```
#This is a two dimensional array:
my_array = [["r1c1","r1c2"],["r2c1",Prawn::Table::Cell.new(:text => "r2c2", :border_width => 1 , :borders => :bottom)]]

#Table
pdf.table my_array, :border_width => 0
```

Well, with this code I have a 2x2 table with no borders!

Has someone any tip?

Comment: Do you need to add in a Prawn::Document object to render onto ?

I noticed in the docs the following:

Creates a new cell object. Generally used indirectly via Document#cell

Of the available options listed below, :point, :width, and :text must be provided. If you are not using the **Document#cell shortcut**, the :document must also be provided.

Answer (score 0):

Here one solution better known as workaround:

```
#This is a two dimensional array:
my_array = [["r1c1","r1c2"],["r2c1",Prawn::Table::Cell.new(:text => "r2c2", :border_width => 1 , :borders => [:bottom])]]

#Table
pdf.table my_array, 
#:headers => ["h1","h2"],
:border_style => :underline_header
```

Omitting *headers => ["h1","h2"]* you avoid the underlined header.